# So, "Tom, you are wonderful" can only be understood under a specific context, Right?

Tags: meaning-in-context

See,the definition of  "**wonderful**" in http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wonderful?q=wonderful

> 1. very good, pleasant or enjoyable
>
>    *We had a wonderful time last night.*
>
>    *You've all been absolutely wonderful!*
>
>    *It's wonderful to see you!*
> 2. making you feel surprise or admiration
>
>    *It's wonderful what you can do when you have to.*

So, if I say "**Tom, you are wonderful**" to Tom, then it could mean

> 1. Tom is very good and pleasant
> 2. Tom is making you feel surprise or admiration

So, *"**Tom, you are wonderful**" can only be understood under a specific context, Right?*

Comment: 'So' is still usually used as a connective (ie after some setting of the scene), even when it is a person's first word. But in general, almost **any** word can only be fully understood in a specific context (if then). Words tend to be highly polysemic. Here, caution needs to be exercised if there is no obvious trigger for the praise; it's sending a strong signal.

Comment: There is virtually no English sentence one might utter which has a fixed meaning, regardless of context.

Answer (score 1):

Context is usually critical to understanding the nuance of a sentence. In the case of your example, tone of voice alone could make this a sarcastic comment.

There is also the issue of semantic drift. Here's an example of [amusing, awful and artificial](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/10/31/st-pauls-cathedral/) purportedly being taken as amazing, awe inspiring and artistic.

In the case of the word *wonderful*, I suspect the second definition you list relates directly to something inspiring wonder while in the first definition, there is some semantic drift to a somewhat more casual / generic emotion. The [dictionary.com definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wonderful) keeps the same order but expresses this difference more clearly:

> **wonderful** *adjective*
>   1. excellent; great; marvelous: *We all had a wonderful weekend*.
>   2. of a sort that causes or arouses wonder; amazing; astonishing: *The storm was wonderful to behold*.

Modern usage of *wonderful* typically relates to the first definition, but "Tom is very good and pleasant" isn't the natural sense of your example sentence. The natural sense is an expression of appreciation or admiration for something Tom has done.

Comment: So, what about "*I feel wonderful*" is natural or isn't natural?

Comment: @Tom Your new sentence "I feel wonderful" is well formed, if that's what you're asking. My comment about *natural sense* was comparing "Tom is very good and pleasant" with the original. Both have a natural sense, but they don't match well. Also, even assuming that you are the Tom of the example, your new sentence "I feel wonderful" is different from the natural sense of the original (i.e. not the same idea) - one says how you feel, the original says how Tom made the speaker feel.